# Categories and Subcategories Table Structure - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

An admin can create multi category and subcategory.

for example what admin can :

```
cat1                            cat2
   ->sub1                         ->sub1
   ->sub2                            ->sub1_1
   ->sub3
      ->sub3_1
      ->sub3_2
         ->sub3_2_1
         ->sub3_2_2
   ->sub4
      sub4_1
   -sub5
```

I don't know what is the best choice? I should a table or two tables ?

It's what I know:

```
id    title   parent_cat_id

1      cat1        0
2      sub1        1
3      sub2        1
3      sub3        1
4      sub3_1      3
5      sub3_2      3
6      sub3_2_1 5
7      sub3_2_2 5
...
```

Comment: As you have so many categories and sub categories, better to create two tables.

Comment: I would like to say it's the right way to define category and sub-category in same table because we can go through the multiple level and we never know the depth so we can't maintain in more than one table. Anyways if you maintain it in multiple table then it will be problematic while fetching records in performance term and other complications. I am also using same for my accounting software as Saving->Current Saving->abc,xyz

Comment: [This article might be a good resource](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) of exploring the different trade offs to modeling your data, but generally I'd say an adjacency list is fine for most primitive needs and only requires one table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best is a relative term, but we can certainly explore the trade-offs of the available solutions to storing hierarchical data structures in a relational DBMS. Relational databases tend to be flat structures, because they're typically normalized as 2-dimensional tables, made up of columns interesting with rows. This makes the very idea of a nested structure rather difficult to store in such a database.

There are two common ways to store this type of data in your relational database. Specifically, as an **adjacency list**, or using **modified preorder traversal**.

- ### Adjancey list approach

  - #### Pros

    - Easy to implement and understand
    - You can easily migrate a large sub category into another parent
    - No huge cost of writes to the database no matter how large the structure grows
  - #### Cons

    - A lot more expensive to read (*requires a lot of iteration/recursion to rebuild the structure*)
    - Easy to break your data in SQL (SQL doesn't do recursion)
- ### Using preorder traversal

  - #### Pros

    - Easier to find all parents in SQL
    - Easier to not break the data in SQL
    - Cheaper to build the entire tree
  - #### Cons

    - Slightly harder to implement
    - Cost of insertion/update grows as the structure deepens

Now, in your case specifically, it doesn't matter if you have the `title` column in the table that stores your `id` and `parent_id`, because you depend entirely on the primary key of the `parent_id`.

The adjacency list approach is similar to the one you're stating in your question. You don't need two tables to do that, because you use the `id` and `parent_id` fields as an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) to compose and decompose the structure.

The preorder traversal does require using two tables (one to store the categery name or `title` in your case, and one to store the relationship of a parent to its children). Instead of storing the `id`, and `parent_id` in each row, you need to store the `left` and `right` child nodes of every parent node.

```
categories table
----------------
id    title
1     cat1
2     subcat1_1
3     subcat1_2
4     subcat1_2_1



Relationship table
------------------
parent_id      left      right
------------------------------
1              2         3
3              4         NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

Categories and sub-categories are both just logical 'categories' so there's no need to implement more than one physical table unless your design has a specific requirement to do so (although I can't think of one right now...).

Additionally, there's no need to have a structure specifically for each level in your hierarchy; a single table with a self referential join back to the parent at each 'category' (or 'sub-category') level is all you need.

I'm assuming in this example that your categories (or sub-categories) may contain elements so:

```
// categories table 
category_id
category_name
element 
parent_category_id
```

This solution is elegant and allows for expansion of your hierarchy without changing the table.

DML for top level categories are made with the predicate "parent_category_id IS NULL".

DML for lower level categories (or sub-categories) are made with the predicate "parent_category_id = 'whatever the parent category ID is'".

Cheers
Scott

P.S. I don't have enough rep to respond directory to Sherif's answer, and I might be (read probably am) missing something, but a modified preorder transversal (or nested set) can also be implemented with a single table; method and comparison with Adjancey list are described well in [this document](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

I do agree with the pros and cons of each method as described by Sherif.